# CI Route Issue Not Getting Variable

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having an issue with this route and not sure what my problem is exactly.

My page is located at http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/pmsystem/viewmessage/1  where 1 is the message id.

I set up a route to look like

```
$route['pmsystem/viewmessage/(:num)'] = 'pmsystem/viewmessage/$1';
```

and I'm still getting a error message like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Pmsystem::viewmessage()

Filename: controllers/pmsystem.php

Line Number: 76


// View A Message
function viewmessage($message_id)
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '<script src='.base_url().'../assets/js/cpanel/personalmessages.js></script><script src='.base_url().'assets/js/mylibs/jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js></script>';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    // Checks to see if a session is active for user and shows corresponding view page
    if (!$this->loggedin->chkLoginStatus() === FALSE) 
    {
        if( ! $this->uri->segment(3))
        {
            redirect('error', 'refresh');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
    $bodyContent = 'viewpm';//which view file
    $bodyType = "full";//type of template                   

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->data['user_data'] = $this->users->getUserByUserId($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->data['users'] = $this->loggedin->getUserList();
    $this->data['personal_messages'] = array($this->pmmodel->getTotalMessages($this->session->userdata('user_id')), $this->pmmodel->getTotalUnreadMessages($this->session->userdata('user_id')), $this->pmmodel->getLast5Messages($this->session->userdata('user_id')));
    $this->data['messages'] = array($this->pmmodel->getInboxMessages($this->session->userdata('user_id')), $this->pmmodel->getSentMessages($this->session->userdata('user_id')));
    //$this->data['message_data'] = $this->pmmodel->getPmMessage($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->view('cpanel/index', $this->data);
}
```

UPDATE

```
 // Checks to see if a session is active for user and shows corresponding view page
    if (!$this->loggedin->chkLoginStatus() === FALSE) 
    {
        if (!is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)))
        {
            $this->data['message_data'] = 'Invalid message id!';
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['message_data'] = $this->pmmodel->getPmMessage($this->uri->segment(3));
        }
        $bodyContent = 'viewpm';//which view file
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template
```

Comment: What does your controller look like, specifically the `viewmessage` function? By the way, your route is redundant - it changes nothing, what are you expecting it to do that isn't already done by default?

Comment: I updated my code for you. Thanks for your reply. When there is no id set I want it to be redirected to the error controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route is unnecessary - it doesn't change anything.

```
$route['pmsystem/viewmessage/(:num)'] = 'pmsystem/viewmessage/$1';
```

You can remove that route. The problem is here:

```
function viewmessage($message_id) // no default value means it's required
{
    // your code
}
```

Your controller methods literally accept user input as arguments (whatever's in the address bar). You always have to account for those required arguments not being present in CI controller methods.

```
function viewmessage($message_id = NULL)
{
    if ( ! $message_id) show_404();
    // your code
}
```

This will silence the errors and show a 404 if the required `$message_id` is not there. Additionally, `$this->uri->segment(3)` is unnecessary because it *should* have the same value as `$message_id`.

I highly discourage redirecting to an error page when you really want a 404, but that's up to you. It sure doesn't help the user realize their mistake when the address is lost after the redirect, and you're sending the wrong HTTP headers by doing so.

Comment: I fixed that however what I'd like to do is find out if its numeric and if not then have it send a message to the view that no message was specified. I do have my code above updated. What I'd like to know if this is good enough to go with and if it is how should I handle the fact that what if its someone that isn't the sender or recipient trying to access the message. At what point should I block their access to that message.

Comment: Just pass it to the DB and see if you get a result. No point in validating it in any other way.

Comment: Once again, you're getting a bit out of scope. You have to make sure the message, if found, should be able to be viewed by the user. *How* that's done depends on the internals of your application, I'd assume you're checking a `recipient_id` against the current user id...

Comment: I tried the above and its still echoing the 3rd segment but even if its not numeric

Comment: You should really read the docs on [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), it allows things like `ea12f5`. Like I said, no need to check that anyways - just pass it to your DB and see if you get a result. If not, then handle the error. If it's not valid, then you won't get a result. You can't assume that just being a number will give you a result. Make sense?